# Doctrine: Uknown column type

Tags: php, symfony, exception, types, doctrine-orm

I had column type "eInvoicePaymentStatus" in my project. But later decided I don't need one. I deleted all the references to this type. But now I am geting this error

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Unknown column type "eInvoicePaymentStatus" requested. Any Doctrine type th
at you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType().
You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::g
etTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you m
ight have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use Ab
stractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types impl
ement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might ha
ve a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

when i run

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I deleted doctrine and symfony cache. All also double check for posible references.

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve the SQL queries (with --dimp-sql) then run them directly in phpMyAdmin (or similar, according to your database) ?

Comment: If I run `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` I get the same exception.

Comment: Can you post your `Entity`, I'd assume you set wrong column type on one of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found a solution. In database we have diferent shemas with the same tables. We forgot to delete column in one of the tabel in schema. After deleting column with type 'eInvoicePaymentStatus' everything started to working again.

It was the problem in comment on column.